# How can I create bass like in "HandClap"?

Tags: production

The chorus section of "HandClap" has one of the best bass tracks I have ever heard.  It's powerful yet blends seamlessly and cohesively with the rest of the mix.  Does anyone have any specific clues or ideas as to how specifically this was achieved?

So far I haven't had a lot of luck trying to duplicate this sound.  Usually it comes out too quiet and gets lost, and then when I turn it up it just overpowers my mix.  Do I just need to be more careful with my mixing, is it related to the EQ settings I'm using, do I need to add more instruments, or is it something else I need to do?

**How can I create a bass track that is powerful yet blends well with other tracks?**

Comment: Hi Bob - that looks much more answerable. You are looking to gain clarity of the bass, yes? We do have a few questions on this already - look in the sidebar to the right, especially http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24759/making-all-elements-clearly-audible-in-the-mix?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds, to me, like a relatively standard electric bass with a tad of distortion. The doubling with the bari sax is probably part of the thing that makes it cut through so nicely. It's also mixed fairly far forward, with just a touch of reverb. I think the rest of the track is very carefully EQ'ed to leave space for the bass as well by cutting the frequencies where the bass sits, in the rest of the tracks (except for the bari sax). Give that a shot and see how it works.

Comment: "carefully EQ'ed to leave space for the bass" This is usually achieved by attaching a frequency (spectrum) analyzer to the tracks to find the frequency range any one instrument is using, and then applying EQ on *the other tracks* to duck the volume for those ranges. Sort of like carving out frequency lanes.